# IBOutlet on NSToolbarItem subclass causes image to disappear and interaction to be disabled

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstoolbaritem

I am implementing a preferences window, with a subclass of `NSToolbarItem` that has an `IBOutlet` to an `NSView` (the idea being that when an item is clicked, it will display its view). However, when I connect a toolbar item to an instance of the subclass, that item's image disappears and it is not clickable (although the text remains dark and does not fade).

If I disconnect the `IBOutlet`, everything works again (well, nothing does, since it isn't bound to the view, but you get the idea).

Comment: Is it a plain NSView, some other kind of stock Cocoa view, or a custom view? What do you mean by “when I connect a toolbar item to an instance of the subclass [of NSToolbarItem]”? What action are you hooking the toolbar item up to?

Answer (score 1):

Connecting the view to the `NSToolbarItem` actually sets the view where the toolbar item's image normally is. This is useful in cases where you need a view in the toolbar (for example, the iTunes volume slider), but not in your case.

What you need to do is create an `NSViewController` for your view, and create an `IBAction` that shows the view. You should be able to connect the `IBAction` to the toolbar item (in Interface Builder), and everything should work as expected.